# Is there any way we can pause kafka stream for certain period and resume later?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have one requirement where we are using Kafka Streams to read from Kafka topic and then send the data over network through a pool of sessions. However, sometimes, network calls are bit slow and we need to frequently pause the stream, ensure we are not overloading network. Currently, we capture data into a stream and load it to a executor service and then send it over network through session pool.

If data in executor service is too high, we need to pause the stream for some time and then resume it once backlog on executor service is cleared up. For achiveing this pause mechanism, We are currently closing the stream and starting again once backlog is cleared up.

Is there any way we can pause the kafka stream?

Comment: You can modify the flow so that, Kafka Stream write down to another Topic. And make Executor service to read from that topic on demand of the network load.

Comment: The underlying consumer API to `pause()/resume()` is not available in Kafka Streams. If you really need it, you would need to fall back to write a plain `KafkaConsumer` application instead of using the Streams API.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there is nothing special you need to do. You are talking about "back pressure" and Kafka Streams can handle it out of the box.

What can be done is putting this data into a queue with some max size and use this queue to load in executor service. Whenever the queue reaches some threshold, there are two methods:

- If your call to put data in queue is blocking with no time-out, there is nothing more you need to do. Just wait until the system is back online, your call
  returns, and processing will resume.
- If your call to put data in queue is blocking with time-out,just issue the lookup to check the size of the queue. Repeat this until the system is back online and your call succeeds.

The only caveat is that as long as your Streams application blocks, the internally used Kafka consumer client will not send any heartbeats to Kafka and might time out. Thus, you need to set the time-out configuration parameter higher than the expected maximum downtime of your external system.

Another approach is to use a Processor API available in Kafka-streams, though, it is not usually recommended pattern.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: It is always helpful to give the source of your wisdom, especially if you are copying parts verbatim, which in this case you did from here: https://groups.google.com/g/confluent-platform/c/Nyj3eN-3ZlQ/m/lMH-bFx-AAAJ